# How do nested tags work in E4X?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript, e4x

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
var foo:XML = <root><a>this is a <b>special</b> case</a></root>
```

Is there any way to detect the position of `<b>` relative to the contents of `<a>` without a custom subparser?

Comment: what do you mean by detect it's position? find out if b is a child of a?

Comment: What I meant was if I were to call text() on the above, I'd get "this is a  casespecial" instead of "this is a special case". Is it possible to detect the b tag is at neither "end" of the a tag.

Sorry I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your data inside [CDATA tags](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp), So it isn't based as XML.

Then you can set a textfields htmlText property to get the formatting.

Comment: I didn't ask about TextField or it's properties. This question is about E4X and the XML class.

Comment: Your question is tagged "actionscript-3" so I just assumed. You should think more about your tags!

Comment: No no, the tag is correct. It is an actionscipt 3 project I'm working on. It's just that I'm not using TextField for it. I was planning to use XML to serialize data users entered into a custom UI control.

It's essentially a very primitive HTML control like the built-in TextField class, but it uses runtime loaded SVG fonts so it couldn't be based on TextField.

What I have ended up doing is serializing the data I'm grabbing from the object through it's inner display tree. When it comes to deserializing I would have preferred to handle an input format like the code block in my original post...

Comment: ...ie I'd rather nest tags like in an HTML document rather than creating siblings.

Anchor tags for example would be `p ... a ... /a .../p` rather than `p ... /p a ... /a p ... /p`.

Sorry I didn't explain properly the first time :-)